# Beginning with $250$ grams of a radioactive substance. After $250$ minutes, the sample has decayed to $32$ grams. Write an exponential equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm working on this problem:

> A scientist begins with 250 grams of a radioactive substance. After 250 minutes, the sample has decayed to 32 grams. Write an exponential equation representing this situation.

I arrived at $f(t)=250e^{-0.008223t}$ whereas my textbook solution section says it's $f(t)=250e^{-0.00914t}$

My working:

First find $k$:

$$y=A_oe^{kt}$$
$$32=250e^{250k}$$
$$\frac{32}{250}=e^{250k}$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{32}{250}\right)=250k$$
$$k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{32}{250}\right)}{250}$$
$$k=-0.008223$$

Thus my exponential function is $A(t)=250e^{-0.008223t}$.

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at the correct solution $f(t)=250e^{-0.00914t}$?

Comment: I'm convinced. Seems correct.

Comment: Your solution is correct, provided that your correctly cite all the numbers.

Comment: Oh! That's great I guess! For interest, here's the page of the online textbook with the exercise. Near the bottom is exercise 33, https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-7-exponential-and-logarithmic-models.

The solution to 33 is shown under 6.7 exercises over here https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-6

Comment: I am convinced that your sample still has a mass of 250 grams, but now mainly consists of different substance ...

Comment: Congratulations! You found an error in the online-source.